# "Invalid protocol" when trying to connect to Elasticache Redis in Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, node-redis

I'm trying to connect an ElastiCache Redis to an Express server deployed on ECS. I'm using the [Official Redis package for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

I get the Primary Endpoint from ElastiCache as `blablabla.mccjet.ng.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379`

In my server I try to connect like this

```js
const { createClient } = require("redis");
const pubClient = createClient({ url: 'blablabla.mccjet.ng.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379' });
```

But when I check the ECS logs I see

```bash
/usr/src/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:124
throw new TypeError('Invalid protocol');
^
TypeError: Invalid protocol
at Function.parseURL (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/c...
```

Haven't used Redis so no idea why this is happening. Any idea how to use the endpoint properly

even tried with

```js
const pubClient = createClient({ host: 'blablabla.mccjet.ng.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com', port:6379 });
```

but that also didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was I had to add the prefix `redis://` before my **Primary endpoint** so that it becomes `redis://blablabla.mccjet.ng.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379`
[Github Issue](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/2201)

```js
const pubClient = createClient({ url: 'redis://blablabla.mccjet.ng.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379' });
```